# How to sort messages alphabetical

Tags: sorting, ibm-midrange, iseries-navigator

wrkmsg - How can I sort messages alphabetically?

Is there any possible way to sort those messages in a way that I like to have them?

Comment: I was informed, that there is an option to send queue to file (no spooled file) and then sort. So there can be no other way AFAIK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean that you want to sort the message definitions stored in a message file, rather than the current contents of a message queue.  You can create a database table (ie. a file) to receive the message descriptions, and then do whatever you'd like with those records.

Normally you can `DSPMSGD` to a print file.  But we will create a physical file or table, and override the output of the `DSPMSGD` command to our file.  The first three records are trash, for our purposes, and we will discard them using `CPYF` from a workfile into our final file.

Make things easier by setting your library as current.

```
CHGCURLIB mylib
```

You could define your files in DDS, but I'll demonstrate this in SQL.

```
STRSQL
```

To create your work file and result file:

```
CREATE TABLE qtemp/workfile
( x1      char(1),
  msgid   char(7),
  sev     char(2),
  msgtxt  char(132)
)

CREATE TABLE myfile
( msgid   char(7),
  sev     char(2),
  msgtxt  char(132)
)
```

Exit SQL to return to a command line.

Override the output file for the `DSPMSGD` command to your work file, and collect your data.

```
OVRDBF QPMSGD workfile
DSPMSGD RANGE(*FIRST *LAST) MSGF(some_msgf) 
    DETAIL(*BASIC) OUTPUT(*PRINT)
CPYF workfile myfile MBROPT(*replace) 
    FROMRCD(4) FMTOPT(*MAP *DROP)
```

You can now go back into SQL and see the fruits of your labor.

```
STRSQL

SELECT *
 from myfile
 order by msgtxt
```

Comment: Rather than dumping the message spool to a database file, I would suggest using the [QMHRTVM](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/topic/apis/QMHRTVM.htm) to sequentially retrieve the message's and dump the contents to a table.

Comment: Yes, if you need the additional fields provided by the API, and understand programming with API's then that could be a better approach.  Without knowing more about the questioner, and looking at the question, I felt a simple and quick approach might be more appropriate in this case.

Comment: @kidzior - can you provide more information about what you want to do with the sorted messages?

Answer (score 0):

Not that I have ever seen. They come appear in datetime order. I am sure they are stored in a physical file somewhere where you could maybe query it, but I usually clear out my messages ASAP.